# C# How to access Form1 controls from Form2 and get not affected when minimized

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Good day.

**What I need to achieve:**
Still access **Form1** controls (more on performclick buttons) & when I minimize the **Form1**, the **Form2** is not get affected.

Want to copy >> [Jitbit Macro Recorder Toolbar when recording or playing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrzNU.png)

**What i got:**

**Form1:**

```
Form2 form2= new Form2();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     form2.Show();
}
```

**Form2:**

```
Form1 form1;

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     form1 = (Form1)this.Owner;
}

private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     form1.buttonRecord.PerformClick();
     form1.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with _"when I minimize the Form1, the Form2 is not get affected."_ How is Form2 affected by Form1's minimize?

Comment: `form1.Show();` shouldn't it be  `form2.Show();`?

Comment: oh yeah thats a typo thats "form2.Show();" I just copy paste xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to go down that road you could make your click handler public and call it.

Form1:

```
Form2 form2= new Form2();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     form2.Owner = this;
     form2.Show();
}

public void ButtonRecord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Form2:

```
Form1 form1;

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     form1 = (Form1)this.Owner;
}

private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     form1.ButtonRecord_Click(sender, e);
     form1.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
}
```

What you are basically doing is a cirlucar reference between the two forms, which is not ideal. You could consider using events like this:

Form1:

```
Form2 form2= new Form2();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     form2.Show();
     form2.Test += (s, ee) => MessageBox.Show("test event");
}
```

Form2:

```
public event EventHandler Test;

private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Test?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```